# Group query using mongoose 4.11.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

I want to make a group using the last version of mongoose for example:

```
    Patient.group({gender:true})
    .then((result)=>{
        console.log(result);
    });
```

**Patient** is the model, do you know how do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is mongoDB [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) pipeline. The following will group the patient documents on the basis of gender:

```
Patient.aggregate(
        [

            //{
            //  $match: {email: {$exists: true}}  //you can also match some criteria
            //},

            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$gender"
                }
            }
        ]
    )
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

Comment: can I group by virtual elements ?

Comment: Mongoose virtuals are put together on client side (node) and not persisted in db. That's why named virtuals. So, no, you can't group on virtuals.